# How to completely remove a package and all related files/directories?

Tags: gnome, command-line, bash, samba

I'm trying to remove samba, I've tried using

```
apt-get --purge samba
```

Which according to the man page is supposed to delete .conf files.  However smb.conf is still there.

Any tips on how to remove all related files/directories?

Comment: Purge removes only files which are installed during the package installation. If the smb.conf is generated by you or by samba itself, then this file is not automatically removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you missed a word, you should use

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove samba
```

or simply

```
sudo apt-get purge samba
```

By the way, the configuration file is created and removed in the *Post Installation/Remove* scripts of the `samba-common` package, a package that is installed by default because needed also for the samba client.

So the `smb.conf` file would only be automatically removed if you remove that package, but it is not advisable to do so without breaking the default installation.